# How do you edit node modules in aws lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

To begin experimenting with Alexa Skills, I followed a short guide.  In that guide, it never covered importing modules or anything to that effect.  That is not the issue, that is just the origin of my curiosity.  So in this scenario, AWS somehow knew exactly what to put into this function (which is driving me insane - because I know it's not that simple).  Moving past that however, now I'm trying to determine where you would edit the node.js modules at?  I don't see any resources list and I've tried downloading the package to no avail.

So in this particular example, there is a module called recipes.  How can I edit that module?  I did NOT import this module.  I built one from a provided template that AWS provided and this was the result.

[image]

If this isn't an appropriate question for this forum, let me know a more appropriate location and I will remove.

Comment: The recipes module is probably part of the template you downloaded from AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel dumb after this, but just in case anyone else gets confused like I did here is how to download everything.

Open up your function in AWS Lambda, then select Actions -> Export function.

[image]

Then select "Download deployment package".

[image]

You can then modify and import as necessary.